# I don't quite understand how to make use of e.oldValue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Edit: I've reworked the function with a loop, but it fills in "undefined values". Can anyone shed some light as to why that would be?

I've set up a scheduling app for a friend. She runs a pet sitting business where you get a free visit every 8 visits. I've set it up so every time the same person makes an appointment, the number of visits is added to the previous number, then I divide by 8 and round it down. So say you schedule 6 appointments, then another 6, it would add up to 12. 12/8 rounded down would be 1, so that's one free visit(this is done inside the sheet). I'm trying to figure out how to store the old value in a new cell so when a new appointment is made, say it adds up to a total of 24 visits, it should show 3 free visits minus however many they earned on the previous scheduling.

I've tried making a function that triggers on edit, I'll paste the code below:

```
function freeVisits(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(s.getName() == "Form responses" && range.getColumn() == 9){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Totals");
    for(var i = 0; i < targetSheet.getActiveRange().getLastColumn() + 6; i++){
         var cell = targetSheet.getRange(6+i, 5).getValue();
         var oldCell = cell.oldValue;
         targetSheet.getRange(6+i, 6).setValue(oldCell);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit), `oldValue` is the previous value in the cell that was edited; if there's a cell with `4` in it and you edit it, `e.oldValue` will hold `4`.

Comment: That much is clear, yes, which is the reason I wanted to use it. My question is, will it register only manual(not function) edits? Or perhaps there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Manual only, when a script makes a change it doesn't trigger the `onEdit()`, but for that you can just call the `onEdit()` directly from your other function.

Comment: @AMolina simply calling `onEdit()` from the other function won't work if the code is using event objects.

Comment: @ross is right, however, you can process the event information in the `onEdit()` and then pass it to a separate function. An `onEdit(e)` can get you an `oldValue`, and from it you can pass that value to a function that updates your sheet.

Comment: @AMolina The `onEdit()` won't be triggered in the first place because OP is trying to get this to run when a function has updated the sheet, not just manual edits.

Comment: @ross I see the Issue, you were right on your first correction, there's no onEdit for when a script changes the sheet.